# Upstart doesn't produce any log on Ubuntu Raring

Tags: 13.04, upstart, logging

I've just installed Ubuntu 13.04 and added custom upstart scripts. These scripts work well and are already in use on other hosts (not Ubuntu).

The problem is, upstart doesn't produce any log of what it does. The only logs are daemon output logs in /var/log/upstart/. When jobs are started or stopped, no log are created. When a job is killed or exits 1, it is respawned, but there is no log of the respawn event in /var/log/*. log-priority is message, but setting it to debug doesn't change anything.

How can I have upstart produce logs of what is does on raring ?

Thanks for your help.

Arthur

Answer (score 1):

I've posted an answer to a similar question: https://askubuntu.com/a/490900/297973. Long story short, the messages should show up in dmesg, and you may need to add `$KLogPermitNonKernelFacility on` to rsyslogd's config to see them in `/var/log`.