# Where are Upstart log messages on Ubuntu 13.X?

Tags: 13.10, upstart, logging, syslog

On Ubuntu 12.04, I can find Upstart log messages in `/var/log/syslog`.

Commands:

```
# initctl log-priority info
# initctl emit hello
```

Log:

```
Apr  1 01:56:56 precise64 kernel: [ 8365.820425] init: Connection from private client
Apr  1 01:56:56 precise64 kernel: [ 8365.821130] init: Handling hello event
```

On Ubuntu 13.10, the messages do not appear in `syslog` or anywhere else under the `/var/log` directory, although commands like `logger hello` work as expected. Should I be looking for them somewhere else? Is there a configuration setting I need to change somewhere?

There’s a [question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/571798/cannot-find-upstart-logs-in-syslog-despite-a-log-priority-of-debug-ubuntu-13-04) from somebody who seems to be having the same problem on Ubuntu 13.04, and more [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372283/upstart-logs-missing) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319258/upstart-doesnt-produce-any-log-on-ubuntu-raring) that may also be describing the same problem. Unfortunately, these questions offer no leads for the problem.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## Edit 2016-06-02

If you're trying to find "Upstart log messages" in general, check `/var/log/upstart/`. That's where Upstart saves `stdout` and `stderr` from Upstart services. Thanks to leopd's answer for pointing this out.

If you're looking for log messages from Upstart itself, that are configured by `initctl log-priority` and emitted by `initctl emit`, read on!

## Short version

The log entries should actually show up in dmesg. Despite that, they do *not* show up by default in `/var/log`.

If you want them in `/var/log` too, add `$KLogPermitNonKernelFacility on` to rsyslogd's config. I suggest creating a custom file like `/etc/rsyslog.d/60-custom.conf` to avoid editing `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, since that's managed by dpkg. Now Upstart messages should show up in `/var/log/syslog`, once you set Upstart's `log-priority` to `info` or so.

## Long version

This took me days to track down, but apparently Upstart (1.5) does *not* log to syslog, that is, it doesn't call the glibc function `syslog()`. Instead, Upstart logs to the kernel ring buffer, which is what dmesg reads. Now, I didn't think it was *possible* for user space processes to write to that buffer, but apparently they can by writing to `/dev/kmsg`, and that's exactly what Upstart does. So that's the first part of the puzzle.

The second part is that there's a widely-held belief that messages written to the kernel ring buffer are automatically copied to syslog by the kernel (at least that's what I always thought). Turns out this is actually done by a user space daemon, traditionally klogd, which operates in tandem with syslogd. Obviously rsyslogd replaces syslogd but apparently it replaces klogd as well (sort of: see notes at the end).

The third part is that messages written to the kernel ring buffer from user space actually look different from messages written from kernel space: they have a different facility. dmesg has a few options that interact with this: `-x` will show the facility (and the priority), while `-u` and `-k` tell dmesg to show only user facility messages and kernel facility messages, respectively.

Now here's the clincher: by default, rsyslogd *ignores* messages with a non-kernel facility when it's reading messages from the kernel ring buffer. The relevant config option is `$KLogPermitNonKernelFacility`, which is off by default and needs to be turned on if you want rsyslogd to process these messages. Note that the rest of rsyslogd's config will treat all messages from the kernel ring buffer as having the `kern` facility, irrespective of the facility they had in the kernel ring buffer.

## More information

### syslog

Code can write to syslog by calling the glibc function `syslog()`, described in `man 3 syslog`. Apparently these functions write to `/dev/log`. Code can read from syslog by reading `/dev/log`, and this is what `syslogd` and its replacements do. `rsyslogd` reads `/dev/log` using its `imuxsock` input module.

### Kernel ring buffer

Kernel space writes to this buffer by calling the kernel function `printk()`, so it's sometimes called the printk buffer. User space can write to it by writing to `/dev/kmsg`. User space can read from this buffer by several methods: it can read from `/proc/kmsg` (what dmesg does by default), or it can read from `/dev/kmsg`, or it can call the system call `syslog()`, which is described in `man 2 syslog` and is *completely different* from the glibc function `syslog()` described in `man 3 syslog`. glibc actually provides a wrapper to the system call `syslog()`, called `klogctl()`, to help alleviate this confusion.

Traditionally, `klogd` reads from one of these interfaces, then calls the glibc function `syslog()` to copy them to the syslog. rsyslogd reads one of these interfaces through its `imklog` input module but AFAIK doesn't bother calling the glibc `syslog()`, which is why it's not exactly like klogd; it just processes the output of `imklog` just like it processes output from any other input module. There is the added caveat that all `imklog` output has the `kern` facility irrespective of the facility messages had in the kernel ring buffer.

## References

- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#initctl-log-priority (Incorrectly states that Upstart logs to syslog)
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/dev-kmsg
- http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Overview-of-Syslog.html
- http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v5-stable/configuration/modules/imklog.html (Note that this is for v5, used in Ubuntu 12.04. These options are considered legacy in recent rsyslog versions)

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation of why this wasn’t working and how to fix it. One of the answers to the linked questions mentioned `dmesg` but it didn’t make any sense without the context given here.

Answer (score 18):

I found mine in `/var/log/upstart/`

Comment: I found mine in the file `/var/log/upstart/job.log` where `job` is the name of my job.

Comment: AFAIK that's where stdout/stderr from jobs go. This question is about log messages from Upstart itself, that aren't associated with any particular job.